# Por que cuando hago una peticion login en la network de brave me deja ver los datos ingresados? pero en la de chrome no?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, http

como estan?

Si alguien tan amable que me pueda explicar porque a la hora de hacer login me muestra email y contraseña en la network de brave, pero en google chrome no.

[image: Antes del login con google crhome]

[image: Despues del login con google crhome]

[image: Antes del login en brave]

[image: Despues del login en brave]

Obviamente no son datos reales, pero si algun dia subo la aplicacion, creo que esto sera un gran problema...

Este es el codigo donde hago la peticion

```
  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
const res = await login({ email: email, password: password });
if (res.status === 201) {
  window.localStorage.setItem("loggedUserId", JSON.stringify(res.data.id));
  window.localStorage.setItem(
    "loggedToken",
    JSON.stringify(res.data.token)
  );
  navigate("/");
}};
```

Este es el codigo de parte del backend

```
async loginUser(loginDto: LoginDto) {
const { email, password } = loginDto;

const user = await this.userSchema.findOne(
  { email: email },
  { _id: true, password: true },
);

if (!user) {
  throw new HttpException('User not found', 404);
}

const checkPassword = await compare(password, user?.password);

if (!checkPassword) {
  throw new HttpException('Password is invalid', 400);
}

try {
  const id = user?._id;

  const payload = { id: id };
  const token = this.jwtAuthService.sign(payload);

  const data = {
    id,
    token,
  };

  return data;
} catch (err) {
  throw new HttpException(err, 400);
}}
```

Comment: Me parece que uno es `http` y el otro `https`? Tal vez la respuesta esté relacionada

Comment: los dos son `http`

Comment: estas comparando el tab "preview" con el tab "payload"... en el tab payload de chrome tambien te deberian salir los datos enviados

Comment: Tienes toda la razon me sale el mail y la password, sabes por que es??